# syntax error! jqGrid problem parsed by Catalyst server.pl

Tags: perl, jqgrid, catalyst

I'm new to Catalyst, I found server.pl built-in in catalyst module can not parse jqGrid correctly.

Below is error messages:
Error: syntax error
Source File: http: //xxx:3000/site/static/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js
Line: 2
Source Code:
 
Error: syntax error
Source File: http ://localhost:3000/site/static/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
Line: 2
Source Code:

But it could parse jquery and jquery-UI perfectly. and There is no any problem if I save it as html page(don't parse by Catalyst server.pl)

Any help are appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message isn't from Catalyst, it's from your browser. Catalyst isn't doing any parsing; it's just serving files directly from the `static` directory. Most likely, there isn't any problem with Catalyst at all and you should check to make sure that the JavaScript file is valid and was placed on the server correctly. If you're 100% sure that's not the problem, you should try downloading  `http://xxx:3000/site/static/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js` using a tool like wget or curl and compare it to the original, then come back here and update your question with a description of any differences.

Comment: Thanks! wget is a amazing way to find my fault.